# Anaconda error in spyder for building pybinding

Tags: installation, spyder, libraries, pybinding

Runtime error: CMake not found. Version 3.1 or newer is required [end of output]
note: This error orignates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for bypinding
Running setup.py clean for pybinding
Failed to build pybinding
Error: Could not build eheels or pybinding, which is required to install project.toml-based projects
how to resolve these error in anaconda.

I am expecting a good solution of my problem